# C# do nested classes need to be instantiated?

Tags: c#

In the following scenario:

```
public class outerclass
{
   public innerClass Ic
     {get;set}

   public class innerClass
   {

   }
}
```

Do you need to instantiate the inner class property before assigning values to it, like this?

```
public class outerclass
{
   public outerclass()
     {
        this.Ic = new innerClass(); 
     }

   public innerClass Ic
     {get;set}

   public class innerClass
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Just compile it, call it, and see what happens, you pretty much have the code all written already.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter in what scope class has been declared - you should always work with classes in the same manner: before interacting with a particular class instance you have to **create** it using `new` operator.

Comment: So the constructor of the outerclass is the correct place to create the new instance?

Comment: @JL: Depends on how you plan to use it.  That's one place you can instantiate it.

Comment: Sure. A constructor is the place, where the initial (required for further working) state of an object is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unlike a base class you need to instantiate an inner class if you wish to use it.

You can prove this to yourself quite easily by trying it:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public InnerClass Ic { get; set; }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        public InnerClass()
        {
            Foo = 42;
        }

        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new OuterClass().Ic.Foo);
    }
}
```

The above code throws a NullReferenceException because `Ic` has not been assigned.

I would also advise you to follow the Microsoft naming convention and use pascal case for type names.

Comment: Yes, just hand typed the example :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case the answer doesn't depend on the fact that the class is defined inside your outer class.  Because you used the automatic getter/setter, a hidden backing field is used for the property `Ic`.  Like all fields of reference type, this field has a default value of `null`.  Thus if you try to access the members of `Ic` without setting it to refer to some instance, you can expect a `NullReferenceException`.

Everything I just said would still be true even if `innerClass` was defined somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

No, the property is an instance of the class. The set would set a new instance anyway.  No need to construct one unless you want to make sure the get never returns null.